# Can this example of jQuery .attr() be exploited by XSS attack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

Below I have an example that is being flagged by my code scan tool as a potential XSS vulnerability:

```
$('#someField').attr('value', $('#dropdown option:selected').text());
```

This is just setting the *value* attribute of a field using the selected option text of a dropdown menu. Assuming the text of the dropdown option is unsafe and untrusted, how can this be exploited via XSS? (Note this code gets triggered to run when a separate dropdown change event is fired).

Comment: Similar question at Information Security SE: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160175/is-there-a-possability-to-inject-xss-into-the-jquery-attr-function/160177

Comment: Yes I saw that answer, but I am looking for an independent confirmation that this example is safe.